# Rails & Active Record Query to get objects without child objects that belong to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

An Event has many Votes. A User has_many votes. A Vote belongs to a User and an Event.

I am trying to render all the events that a particular User has not voted for. Here is my query but it is returning all events:

```
Event.includes(:votes).where("votes.user_id != ? OR votes.user_id IS NULL", current_user.id).references(:votes)
```

I double checked in the controller and the user has voted 3 times. `Event.all` gets me 820 events. `Event.includes(:votes).where("votes.user_id = ?", current_user.id).references(:votes)` gets me 3 (correct). But I am trying to build a query that will return me 817 results.

There are 236 votes total. 3 are from the current user. When I run my query, I'm returning all the events where other users have voted (233 events have votes from other users). Instead, I want to return all the events with votes from other users (233) AND the other events without votes

`Event.includes(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id = ?", current_user.id).references(:votes)` gets me 233 results (because other users have voted for some events).

How can I build this query?

Comment: Did you try `Event.includes(:votes).where.not('votes.user_id': current_user.id).references(:votes)`?

Comment: @ArunKumar yes, same result

Comment: hmm. Might be silly. Are you sure that the user you're testing has voted for an event?

Comment: Haha, good question. Yes I double checked in the controller and the user has voted 3 times. Event.all gets me 820 events. Event.includes(:votes).where("votes.user_id = ?", current_user.id).references(:votes)  gets me 3  (correct).  But I am trying to build a query that will return me 817 results.

Comment: Event.joins(:votes).where("votes.user_id = ?", 9).count returns 3. Event.joins(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id = ?", 9).count returns 233 instead of 817

Comment: There is 236 votes total. 3 are from the current user. So when I run my query, I'm returning all the events with the other 233 votes. Instead, I want to return all the events with 233 votes AND the events with no votes.